# Class filre editor:Source not found error

Tags: android, eclipse

during my android app debugging in eclipse, I'm encountering with an error saying:
Class File Editor
Source not found
The JAR file c:...\android-17\android.jar has no source attachment. you can attach the source by clicking attach source below

What's the cause of this error? in my android SDK manager, I have API17 installed.
The code that produce this error during the debug is this:

```
    String[] Fields = wsOutput.split("##");
    EditText EditTextSharesCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextSharesCode); 
    EditTextSharesCode.setText(Fields[0]);
```

before third line execution, Field[0] is equal to "25". I'm really confused about this.

Answer (score 0):

check Fields.length and  check wsOutput contains "##" or not

Comment: As I mentioned before, the error is happening in third line. and the value of Fields[0] is "25". so the first lines are working fine.